# Firebase Authentication id token expires before the expiration time

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, polymer

I have the following architecture:

1. Front End
2. Firebase Authentication
3. Node.js Backend

Before each API call, I verify the Firebase ID Token. As per the documentation, the expiration time of the ID token is 1 hour. So, I refresh the token from the Front End every 45 minutes.

But after 2 - 3 refresh events, the ID token expires before the expiration time.

So, is there any way to keep the token always usable?

Comment: I guess you have some middleware functions (controller) where flows all api requests. In my application where I am using firebase auth, I am checking every failed request and if it is about expired token, I send one more request with refresh and then repeat the original request. It takes time to programme such thing, but with fetch api it is possible with just few lines of code

Comment: For that, I need to code in the each and every error handler of AJAX request because from common place I cannot send the original request again. Right?

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský FYI: I am using Google Polymer in front-end and i am using iron-ajax to send AJAX request.

Comment: sorry, I have never used iron-ajax. for me it was absolutely pointless.. Their approach isn't something I wanted. The best practise (propably) for application is to have some centralized point, where goes all requests to the api and data back to the application. So, I can;t help you :/

Comment: Okay. is there any way you know that we can centralize the logic and we can send the original request again?

Comment: it also depens on what version of polymer you are using. for Polymer 2 I had my own custom element which i inserted in the root directory and then set its reference to window so all elements across the application could use it. IN this element you can have some request function which just handles requests with api using fetch API or xhttpRequest. In polymer 3 you can use import/export system. so you can create function which handles requests and import it in every single element you want

Comment: Okay, I am using Polymer 3. I have added common interceptor logic to set Authorization header but I am confused on whether I can send the original API which is failed, from a common place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182580/discussion-between-kuba-simonovsky-and-mitul-gedeeya).